# Add number in the string after each letter

Tags: r, regex, string

I have several strings with a fixed format.

The format is one letter followed by a number, e.g., A3B1C7D1.

However, if the number behind a letter is 1, the string is written as A3BC7D.

What I want to do is to insert number 1, and convert the string from `A3BC7D` to `A3B1C7D1`.

My example data is

```
strings <- c("A", "A3BC3", "A2B1C")
```

What I want to get is:

```
strings_new <- c("A1", "A3B1C3", "A2B1C1")
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option:

```
gsub("([A-Za-z])(?=[A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z])$", "\\1\\21", strings, perl = T)
```

Output:

```
[1] "A1"     "A3B1C3" "A2B1C1"
```

Or if you only have capitals, just:

```
gsub("([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z])$", "\\1\\21", strings, perl = T)
```

Basically this finds letters that are either followed by another letter or are at the end of string, and replaces them with themselves while at the same time adds the desired number, `1` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Find all (uppercase) letters (`[A-Z]`) that is not followed by a number and replace it with that string + `1`:

```
gsub("([A-Z])(?![0-9])", "\\11", strings, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "A1"     "A3B1C3" "A2B1C1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings[!grepl("[0-9]$",strings)]=paste0(strings[!grepl("[0-9]$",strings)],"1")
[1] "A1"     "A3BC3"  "A2B1C1"
```

We first `grep` all positions that do not end with a number, and paste a `1` to them.

Comment: Almost. Check the second element it should be `"A3B1C3"`