# How to add number in the string according to upper case or lower case?

Tags: r, regex, string

The chemical formulae (strings) are always written in a specific format, a chemical element followed by one number， e.g., Oxygen O2, carbon dioxide CO2. solidum chloride NaCl

If one element can be presented with one letter, this letter is in upper case, e.g., oxygen `O` and Carbon `C`. Some elements are shown with 2 letters, and only the first letter is in upper case, e.g., sodium `Na`.

So the element is represented with either one or two letters, there are only two cases.

You can see that if number of element is 1, the number 1 will not be written after it.

What I want to do is to add 1 behind these elements.

My example data is

```
strings <- c("O2", "CO2", "NaCl")
```

What I want to get is:

```
strings_new <- c("O2", "C1O2", "Na1Cl1")
```

In programming language, There are strings with a specific format. A upper case letter or one upper case letter and one lower case letter follows one number. If a number behind a letter is missing, and this letter is in upper case, and the letter behind it is also upper case, then 1 will be insert it after this letter. If this letter is in upper case, but the letter behind it is in lower case, 1 will be inserted after the lower case letter.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825764/add-number-in-the-string-after-each-letter

Comment: @akrun Pretty close, I think. You'd just have to tweak the regex to find capital letters not followed by a lowercase letter. Take a look at https://regex101.com, it has a live regex interpreter that will show you *exactly* what your regex is matching and why. It makes figuring out problems like this **much** easier

Comment: Would modify it to `gsub("(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])$", "1", strings, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Or `(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z]|$)` to shorten the regex a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex which either matches an upper case letter (for `C`) or upper case letter optionally followed by one lower case (to support `Na` or `Cl`) and not followed by a digit, which means it needs to be appended by `1`

```
([A-Z][a-z]?)(?!\d)
```

And replace it by `\11`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1eERd/1/)**

Check out this R code demo,

```
strings <- c("O2", "CO2", "NaCl")
gsub("([A-Z][a-z]?)(?!\\d)","\\11", strings, perl = TRUE)
```

Prints,

```
[1] "O2"     "C1O2"   "Na1Cl1"
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sorry I was editing too and your edit got overwritten by mine. Changed `T` to `TRUE`. Thanks for edit.